# typo3 tt_news - single view, 2 domains and one storage folder all news are visible in both 2 domains

Tags: typo3, tt-news

problem description:
i have two domains on one typo3 installation
i have one folder (general record storage page) with tt_news records for both 2 domains
i have two pages with tt_news single view one for each domain
each single view plugin is configured to show news only from selected category.

problem:
each news is available on both domains.
example: 
1. domain1.com/news/title-news-foo.html 
2. domain2.com/newsfromdomain2/title-news-foo.html

ex 1, its ok, news is assigned to category from this domain
ex 2, its wrong, this news should not be displayed here becouse it`s displyaed on domain1.com

It looks that in single view typo3 is not considering Categry mode selection.
So how to resolve this issue, without separing news to indepenedent GRSP ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you split it up into seperate storage folders

This make things a lot easier. It also sounds you are not using the category mode what it is meant for.

Suggestion:

```
-GRSP
-- NEWS DOMAIN A
-- NEWS DOMAIN B
```

In the views on both domains set the correct storage folder.

Comment: the problem is that i have +- 6000 news (many of them with additional content elements).

Comment: the problem is that i have +- 6000 news records (many of them with additional CE elements). I don`t understand "you are not using the category mode what it is meant for", each news have one of more assigned category, each category have his own list or/and latest page.

Comment: Are you using categorys to see for which domain a certain news item is? If not how do you distinguish between the domains?

Comment: i have two main news categories: domain1 (+subcategories) and domain2 (+ subcategories) on pages with list and latest on domain1 i`m displaing news only from subcategories domain1, and on domain2 the same - it works.

Comment: which version of typo3 are you using, and which extension to display the news? i would say make extended TS template on both single view pages and overrule news settings for category there.

Comment: tt_news (mentioned in title of this post) typo3 6.2.24

Comment: did you try my suggested solution, with extended template?

Comment: on each SV page i have TS template (no root) i`m using it to configure tt_news and some other extensions on this page. What should i add to TS on SV page?